# How to set progress bar for parallel_invoke?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, c++11, lambda

What I want is how to get the progress data. I can implement the bar whatever I like. And I'm using Visual C++ 2010, so I can use MFC.

Now, I'm writting multithreaded program. And Microsoft already provides PPL lib since VC++ 2010. The Parallel Patterns Library (PPL) provides algorithms that concurrently perform work on collections of data. It's convenient to implement multithreaded app, but I encounter progress bar problem.

How can I set progress bar for parallel_invoke?

The demo code is as follows:

```
// parallel-invoke-structure.cpp 
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <ppl.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace concurrency;
using namespace std;

// Returns the result of adding a value to itself. 
template <typename T>
T twice(const T& t) {
   return t + t;
}

int wmain()
{
   // Define several values. 
   int n = 54;
   double d = 5.6;
   wstring s = L"Hello";

   // Call the twice function on each value concurrently.
   parallel_invoke(
      [&n] { n = twice(n); },
      [&d] { d = twice(d); },
      [&s] { s = twice(s); }
   );

   // Print the values to the console.
   wcout << n << L' ' << d << L' ' << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a graphical progress bar, or something to print on the console?

Comment: what progress are you trying to track? of each lambda or the progress of the complete computation?

Comment: What to do is pretty different for each possible interface you're using. QT? _Plain_ Windows SDK? MFC? A .NET WinForms front-end? Usually for Windows it can be done with **PostMessage**.

Comment: You'll have to get the progress yourself through your lambdas. How should `parallel_invoke` know how much work has been done inside the lambdas?

Comment: More an idea than an answer: You could pass a progress parameter as a `double` to each of your processes. So that you can track the progress for each thread. The overall progress could be the diameter of those progress parameters. Mind thread savety! BUT then you still didn't take into account that one process might take significantly longer (or shorter) than others. So your progress bar is lying! But aren't progress bars often like this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is off topic, but I would recommend checking out [Cilk](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cilk-plus) instead of PPL.

Here is [a course at MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-172-performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2010/video-lectures/) (from one of the main creators of Cilk) that outlines its pros, cons and specific usage. It's very easy to use and claims to be much more performant than PPL (in case you're concerned about that).

As for your specific question about progress bars, coming up with a percentage is the first task. If you use timers to map which work costs you what (in terms of wall time), you can use that (via a callback from each worker to register work done) to drive the percentage. Once you have your percentage down, hooking it up to a bar (in the shell) or a GUI progress bar is trivial.

Depending on how much work your worker processes do (how granular they are), you may want to consider different methods of [instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29). If you look at [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29), it'll outline many types of profiling (statistical, event based, etc.).

One last note: I find that progress bars are difficult to get right. Anyone can make a bar move. But having it accurately represent a true indication of how much time it will take involves a great understanding of what factors are affecting your performance. As is the case with any computer program, your performance can change based on which system your run it on (cpu architecture, IO bandwidth, network bandwidth). So even if you get it predictable on your box, your clients' boxes may be drastically different--so much so that your progress bar doesn't yield good indications anymore.

Hope that helps...

Comment: A progress bar's job isn't really to indicate how much time is left until the process is finished - it should mainly show how much of the total work has been done already, and *maybe*, based on the speed of finished suboperations, try to deduce the remaining time.

Comment: I think the main point is that a progress bar's progress should be linear (regardless of time or work being represented). So, a pause at 50% progress for 80% of the time would be considered a progress bar fail. Would you agree?

Comment: Not really. It just shows that 50% of the work has been done. You could consider it a very coarse progress bar, but it is one. Of course you can make the progress as fine-grained as you want by updating not only after a task is finished, but also if subtasks finish.